# unable to locate librrd-simple-perl

Tags: apt, package-management, perl

I am unable to install librrd-simple-perl. System says it is "unable to locate package...". I am trying to install it on a fresh Ubuntu Server LTS 22.04.
Am I missing a repository?

Comment: It doesn't exist on any supported release (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=librrd-simple-perl&searchon=names&suite=all&section=all) so where did you get the package name?

Comment: Pre-requisites to install pnp4nagios: https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-core-performance-graphs-using-pnp4nagios-801.html#Ubuntu

Comment: It may be that for Ubuntu 22.04 the package is named "librrds-perl" - what happens if you try to apt install that? https://packages.ubuntu.com/jammy/librrds-perl