# Unable to locate the package librrd-simple-perl in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install this package `librrd-simple-perl` in my ubuntu 20.04 machine. I have updated my machine but somehow this package is not installing. I need it for my `pnp4nagios` as prerequisite.

[See link here.](https://support.nagios.com/kb/article/nagios-core-performance-graphs-using-pnp4nagios-801.html#Ubuntu)

Kindly help me with how to install this from source or change my repo so that I can install it.

```
root@ast-ubt-vm:/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts# apt-get install librrd-simple-perl
Reading package lists… Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information… Done
E: Unable to locate package librrd-simple-perl
root@ast-ubt-vm:/usr/local/nagios/etc/hosts#
```

Comment: Hi - see my comment on https://askubuntu.com/questions/1404242/unable-to-locate-librrd-simple-perl

Comment: Rub in the terminal `apt search librrd` ... to list available packages with `librrd` in their name or description.

Comment: @TommyPeanuts See the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [here](https://sysadminote.com/how-to-install-pnp4nagios-to-display-graphics-in-nagios/) you need to install the following packages

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install rrdtool librrdp-perl php-gd php-xml
```

Although, you should probably install these extra packages for good measure:

```
sudo apt install librrd-dev librrds-perl
```

To show other related packages, run the following command:

```
apt-cache search librrd
```

and you can filter the results using grep like in the following example:

```
apt-cache search rrdtool | grep dev
```

Comment: I managed to solve it. But your solution is correct too.